# How to take backup of aws elasticsearch index in s3 bucket with index name?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

Hi all I have made the configuration to take the back up of AWS elasaticsearch indices to s3 bucket using CURL command. But in S3 bucket folder inside the indices are of different name , Not the index name as in elastic search.

For ex : My index name in elastic search is alb-accesslog-2018-11-28 ,dockerlog-2018-11-28.
but in s3 bucket i got the snapshot like ykUIdAV5RfmS4W1wCJkM9w , 26l0CTj_Qzqan0vOAM9lwQ. I dont which folder belongs to which index?

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific indices in snapshot, crate a snapshot with specific indices.Use the "indices" parameter in the request body.You can also choose the name of snapshot. If you did these things you would know exactly which snapshot is for which index and you would not need to look inside how elastic-search is managing it's snapshot data.

Comment: Hi Avinash Thanks for the reply could please advice the command to upload single index. i used the command like this curl -XPUT 'http://search-mb-production-app-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/alb-accesslog-2018.11.29' 
-d'{
  "indices": "alb-accesslog-2018.11.29",
    "ignore_unavailable": true,
      "include_global_state": false
      }'        but i got the error like {"accepted":true}./sample.sh: line 6: $'-d{\n  "indices": "alb-accesslog-2018.11.29",\n    "ignore_unavailable": true,\n      "include_global_state": false\n }': command not found